# A vector is a linear combination of two other vectors. Find all scalars c.

Tags: linear-algebra

Q: The vector $[13, -15]$ is a linear combination of the vectors $[1, 5]$ and $[3, c].$ Find all scalars c.

My Approach:

$$[13, -15] = x[1, 5] + y[3, c]$$

$$13 = x + 3y \to (1)$$
$$-15 = 5x + cy \to (2)$$

$$(1) \times 5 \Rightarrow 65 = 5x + 15y$$

$$65 = 5x + 15y- (-15 = 5x + cy) \Rightarrow 80 = 15 - cy$$

$$80 = 15 - cy$$
$$65 = -cy$$
$$\frac{-65}{c} = y$$

$$13 = x + 3y \to (1)$$
$$13 = x + 3\frac{-65}{c}$$
$$13 + \frac{195}{c} = x$$

$$-15 = 5x + cy \to (2)$$
$$-15 = 5(13 + \frac{195}{c}) + c(\frac{-65}{c})$$
$$-15 = (65 + \frac{975}{c}) - 65$$
$$-15 = \frac{975}{c}$$
$$c = -65$$

I have no idea if I did this correct because there are no answers in the back of the book. I feel that I did this wrong.

Comment: The question isn't clear. The vector you gave is a linear combination of the other two vectors for any $c \neq 15$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the two vectors $[1,5]$ and $[3,c]$ are linearly independent, you can solve the system.  They are linearly independent when the determinant of the matrix formed by the two vectors is not zero, so we have the condition:

$$ \left| \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 3  \\
5 & c   \end{array} \right| \neq 0$$

which reduces to

$$1\cdot c - 3\cdot 5\neq 0.$$

solving equation for $c$, you can use any value for $c$ such that $c \neq 15$.

The vector $[13, -15]$ is a red herring.  As long as the two vectors are independent you can combine them to form any vector.  (Note that if the first vector $[1,5]$ was linearly dependent with $[13, -15]$, then the second vector would not matter, but it is not.)